# how to get query string value using javascript

Tags: javascript, query-string

i have an URL like the followin,

```
http://test.com/testing/test/12345
```

12345 is the id. I want to take this using query string. How to take this value in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

```
http://test.com/testing/test/12345

var aarr = window.location.href.split('/');
//get last value
var id = aarr[aarr.length -1];
```

or just

```
 var id = window.location.href.split('/').pop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

`document.location.href.split('/').pop()`

Running it on this page yields : `22139563#22139563`

Comment: @drewish (My pc has SSD drive...) :-)

Comment: Voting you up because you beat me on the pop() ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
var id = location.split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the path, not the query string... but you can access the page's URL using  `window.location`.

The path is available at `window.location.pathname` which can be split up using forward slashes: `window.location.pathname.split('/')`

And then you can get the last item of the array: `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `substring`, I think it's lighter than creating an array:

```
var id = window.location.href;
id = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```