# Initializing a variable in script at .php page and not getting it in .js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, initialization, document-ready

In my .php page at bottom

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Atest = 'Hi';

        $.getScript(app_consts.VIEW_JS + 'something.js');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In the something.js file I have writen

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log(Atest);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And in the console value is not printed. I don't know how to get that.

Comment: did you include jquery above in the `<head>`

Comment: @Blueblazer172 yes, also .js file is loaded correctly

Comment: what about `cookies` ?

Comment: When you use [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) the script is executed in the global context. So your code in `something.js` can't access the local variable `test`.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765893/5930557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change scope of variable like..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Atest = 'Hi';

    (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //var Atest = 'Hi';

        $.getScript(app_consts.VIEW_JS + 'something.js');
    });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

you can read more about Javascript Scope from [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)