# Fill textbox of second page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a `javascript` code below which gets me the value on button click. The values are of row from the gridview.

What happens is, whenever I click on the `button`. it takes me to another page. there I want to fill `Circle` value in the `textbox`

Here is my code below. I don't know how to fill the `textbox`. Please suggest

```
function FillINFOTOPAGE(val) {
        var row = val.parentNode.parentNode;
        var SapId = row.cells[0].innerText.trim();
        var Circle = row.cells[8].innerText.trim();
        window.open('UserDataUpdate.aspx', '_blank');
    }
```

Another page html:-

```
<span>CIRCLE :</span>
        <input type="text" id="txtCircle" style="width: 80px;" />
```

Comment: you can use local storage @VVVV: 
//Set a value
localStorage.setItem("data",myvalue);

//Get the value
localStorage.getItem("data");

Comment: you need to pass the some value with end of the url extension *some.com?val=something*. Then retrive the extension from another page via js .Then add with input box

Comment: @prasad: I dont want to use `querystring` ..!

Comment: @vishuminhas: Can u explain with some code, as I am not getting you properly. ?

Comment: @VVVV follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page

Comment: @vishuminhas: the below answer is working fine for me

Comment: @VVVV thats great mark it as an answer then Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible with the sessionStorage

> in first page:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('txt1Val', "value for txtbx 1");
sessionStorage.setItem('txt2Val', "value for txtbx 2");
```

> in second page:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('txt1Val')){
  $("#text1IDNameSelector").val( sessionStorage.getItem('txt1Val') );
  sessionStorage.removeItem('txt1Val');
}
if(sessionStorage.getItem('txt2Val')){
  $("#text2IDNameSelector").val( sessionStorage.getItem('txt2Val') );
  sessionStorage.removeItem('txt2Val');
}
```

Comment: why are u using `sessionStorage.removeItem` but for me it is working as expected

Comment: sessionStorage.removeItem will remove the sessionstorage once you used it.

Comment: but when I use sessionStorage.removeItem the value does not get set in the textbox

Comment: @VVVV its strange but once you used the value should appear in the textbox and remove it from session

Comment: Thanks Dharmendrasinh.!!