# How can I pass a query string to window.location.replace()?

Tags: javascript

I am sending an email that links a user to a URL with a query string. I am retrieving this string with:

```
var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
var string = reg.exec(href);
return string ? string[1] : null;
};

var list = getQueryString('list', window.location.href);
console.log(list);
```

I want to pass this query string to another link on this page. My current function reads as:

```
function signin(){
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(){
    window.location.replace("management.html" + list);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    ...
  });
}
```

How can I correctly pass the variable `list` to `signin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `list` variable only contains the value of the query `'?list=123'` which for example would be `'123'`

You aren't creating a new query string....just adding that same value to end of the new url so it would look like `"management.html123'`

If you want the whole query string from current page passed to new page you can use `location.search`

```
location.replace("management.html" + location.search);
```

Or for just the `'list'` do:

```
location.replace("management.html?list=" + list);
```

Comment: Wow. Almost too easy.

Answer (score -1):

If these are not on the same page and the global variable is not accessible, I would use the local storage solution presented here:

[Passing Variable through JavaScript from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)