# How to send a value which is returning through link?

Tags: javascript

I want value of `total` in another function `call`.

```
function recalculateTotal(sc) {
  var total = 0;
  //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
  sc.find('selected').each(function() {
    total += this.data().price;
  });
  return total;
}

function call() {
  var a = recalculateTotal(sc);
  window.location.replace("Demo2.jsp?name=" + a);
}
```

Comment: this may help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope of variable sc.  Is sc global?  You can do the following:

```
var scInput = 'whatever';
var total;

function recalculateTotal(sc)  {
  var total = 0;
  //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
  sc.find('selected').each(function() {
    total += this.data().price;
  });
  return total;
} 

total = recalculateTotal(scInput);

function call(a) {
  window.location.replace("Demo2.jsp?name=" + a);
}

call(total);
```

Your original code sample is fine so long as the variable sc and call(); are in the same scope.  I think you might be confused by **parameters** vs. **arguments**. In your recalculateTotal function you define a parameter called 'sc'.  However, when you call that function you need to send in an argument (the value of sc).  So your original example is correct in the following instance

```
var sc = 'your-value'

function recalculateTotal(sc)  {
  var total = 0;
  //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
  sc.find('selected').each(function() {
    total += this.data().price;
  });
  return total;
} 

function call() {
  var a = recalculateTotal(sc);
  window.location.replace("Demo2.jsp?name=" + a);
}

call(sc);
```

It is correct in the above example because there exists a variable sc in the global scope that the call function has access to.   The same is also true for this example:

```
var sc = 'your-value'

function recalculateTotal()  {
  var total = 0;
  //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
  sc.find('selected').each(function() {
    total += this.data().price;
  });
  return total;
} 

function call() {
  var a = recalculateTotal();
  window.location.replace("Demo2.jsp?name=" + a);
}

call();
```

The confusion you might have is that in your example you have an argument **sc** in recalculateTotal(sc), and in the call method the attribute you pass I to recalculateTotal(sc) is also called sc. This is correct notation and a very common practice, but it does confuse people who are not familiar with it