# how to display javascript validation message on html popup

Tags: javascript, html

Want to display javascript validation messages inside an html popup window which would be a seperate html page.currently it is displayed on the same page from where it has been called.

```js
 $("#getStarted").val('Try xxxx for Free');
 $('#message1').text('User ' + emailID + ' already exists.');
 $("#stRegister").val("");
 document.getElementById("stRegister").focus();
```

```html
<input name="stRegister" id="stRegister" type="email" class="registerinput" placeholder="Enter your business email ID" onkeypress="$('#message1').text('');">

 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
 <div style="margin-left:8px;" class="alerts" id="message1">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your requirement seems to be unconventional

Comment: Yep, I think he just wanted to say display an HTML block inside a Js popup

Comment: So what is your actual _question_ then? (“I want” is _not_ a proper question/problem description; please go read [ask] if you have not done so yet.) How to open a popup window? Easy enough to research. How to get access to the document inside the popup and manipulate or replace it? Also something you should try and research yourself first.

Comment: Maybe local storage? Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page

Answer (score 0):

var window = window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);  moidify the dom on the window object.

Comment: Tried this     popupWindow = window.open('xxxxx.html', 'xxxxx', 'top=300,left=450,width=500,height=200,resizable=no'); But want to display message inside xxxxx.html.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it in a separate window. However, for validation you can use the `window.confirm` function natively build into the browsers. Here is an example:

```js
// window.confirm returns a boolean based on the user action
let validate = window.confirm('Do you want to continue?');

if (validate) {
  console.log('validated');
} else {
  console.log('not validated');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use in your script something like:

```
window.alert("what you want here");
```