# How can I load a variable from a index.html file to a results.html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make some sort of search engine, I have the input set up, but I need to load the searched tearm into my results page, I am using javascript for this, 1 page for input, one file to store the data, and 1 file to output the data.

INPUT:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
var searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");
var input = "";

searchButton.onclick = function() {
    input = inputBox.value;
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    console.log("Input: " + input);
    getData(input);
}
```

DATASTORE:

```
var storeSearchedTearm = "";

getData = function(whatToStore) {
    console.log("Database collection: " + whatToStore);
    storeSearchedTearm = whatToStore;
    console.log("Database added to store: " + storeSearchedTearm);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
console.log("Data: " + storeSearchedTearm);

var searchedTearm = "";

searchedTearm = storeSearchedTearm;

console.log("Output: " + searchedTearm);
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variable through JavaScript from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

Comment: How are you doing the searching? If it's on the server, you send the search string to it using POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your searched query in Localstorage after pressing Search button in index.html, and get that value in results.html. Try my solution.

Index.html

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
var searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");
var input = "";

searchButton.onclick = function() {
    input = inputBox.value;
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    console.log("Input: " + input);
    localStorage.setItem("searchedQuery",input );
    getData(input);
}
```

Results.HTML or any place you want to see your saved data:

```
var SearchedQuery = localStorage.getItem("searchedQuery");
```