# How can import a javascript variable to another js file from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really a beginner at Javascript. How can I use a script variable from HTML to another js file? I have tried to import and export module. But, I couldn't work.

Here is the js.fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfngowtq/

and that is my error:

`1.js:1 GET .../new.html net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:flask], what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variable through JavaScript from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

Comment: @AhmadHabib — It doesn't seem to be about multiple HTML pages.

Comment: It's unclear why you are asking about passing data between scripts when your error is a simple 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use local storage instead of variables. It will store values across js files

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is using a global variable.

```
window.a = "123" // your HTML 
console.log(window.a) // your script
```

Comment: What does this have to do with using multiple files?

Comment: You can access all `window` properties in all files

Comment: You don't need to explicitly assign to `window.something` to make a global.