# Dynamically load content preserving 'open in new tab' functionality

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, dom-events

I am using javascript to dynamically load page content on my webpage.

I have a number of links, but they do not have `href` attributes. When the user clicks a link, they have a `data-content` attribute which is used as a key to load new content dynamically from a JSON file.

My links look something like this:

```
<a data-content="about">About</a>
```

This works perfectly well.

I know from a UX perspective, users may want to right click a link and load it into a new tab. This current way of doing things does not permit this behaviour.

One way around this would be to move the `data-content` attribute to the `href` attribute and add a `#` before. For example:

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

Right clicking on this link and loading in a new tab would open the URL

```
<a href="mysite.com/my-current-page#about">About</a>
```

I could then use javascript to look for `#` in the URL and use the string after it as a key to find the content to load on the page.

When I make this change though - javascript no longer loads my new content.

So what are some ways of dynamically loading content onto a page whilst preserving the functionality of '`open in new tab`

Comment: One of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)? Otherwise, add to your question how you're loading the data and someone will probably have a fix for the anchor/id approach.