# Is it possible for an html file to access loaded html <script> variable using fetch?

Tags: javascript, html

lets say I have a `page.html` file with this content:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script>var foo_data = "abc"; </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

and then on my `main.html` file I used:

```
<script>
  fetch('/page.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
          document.getElementById('page-content').innerHTML = data;
          console.log(foo_data); // Will not work
    })
</script>
```

Is there a way to access `foo_data` on my `main.html` file or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: there isn't an direct way to do this. what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the use case here? The setup you describe is not possible, and is a pretty poor design. Why not explicitly pass the data between the pages if that's what you need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variable through JavaScript from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

Comment: Your `data` variable contains plain text. So technically you could extract variable value with a regex.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm trying to code a novel-writing app with character profile wiki-like feature. Each pages are stored in a .html but formatted like a markdown file. I want to be able to store data (like hair color, eye color, heght, weight) in a dictionary variable for easy access so i placed them in a script tag. So when i loaded the page.html it contains the markdown formatted text as well as the script tags

Comment: @esqew not really but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @vanowm I suppose i'll have to do that if nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `eval()` method. Basically the idea is parse html in `data` variable, and execute `<script>` elements with eval:

```js
fetch('/page.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
          const html = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
          //this is unnecesary, unless you need to display html
          document.getElementById("page-content").innerHTML = data;
          
          for(let i = 0, scripts = html.querySelectorAll("script"); i < scripts.length; i++)
            eval(scripts[i].textContent); //execute scripts

          console.log(foo_data);
    })
    .catch(er => console.error(er));
    
    
/* ignore below */

async function fetch()
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    resolve(new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      resolve({text: () => `<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script type="javascript">var foo_data = "abc";<\/script> 
<\/body>
<\/html>`});
    }))
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="page-content"></div>
```