# How can I use a variable from another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have two html pages, each with a js file.

When I click on a button on **page 1**, it should change a variable **param** to true and redirect the user to **page 2**.

In **page 2** I have to check if **param = true** and then continue my script.

- page1.html

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="about">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="mainsubtitle">Page 1</div>
    <button id="edit" type="button">Go to page 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

- script1.js

```
var param = false;

edit.addEventListener("click", switchToOpenSession);
...
function switchToOpenSession() {
    param = true;
    ...
}
```

- page2.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div>Page 2</div>
    <button id="create" type="button">Create account</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

- script2.js

```
if (param)
   /* do this */
```

I tried export/import param but I got `Unexpected token 'export' error`. I  tried `type="module"` but it doesn't work. The samples that I found was two js files in the same html page!

Can someone help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variable through JavaScript from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot access variable from different page, except you load `page2.html` using ajax. Alternative way using cookie or `localStorage`

`script1.js`

```
var param = false;

edit.addEventListener("click", switchToOpenSession);
...
function switchToOpenSession() {
    param = true;
    localStorage.setItem('param', true)
    ...
}
```

then in `script2.js`

```
if (localStorage.getItem('param') == 'true') // note the quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

you can export the variable from first file

```
var first;

export { first }
```

and in your second file you can import that variable

```
import { first} from './first.js'
```

OR

```
<script type="module" src='first.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't share variable states like that. These two pages are totally different instances, so the context is not the same.

**Option** 1. When you redirect from one page to another you can add URL param and [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) it on page 2.

**Option** 2. Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). I assume you have the same origin while talking on page 1 and page 2 so the stored data will be visible.

Comment: The second option solved my problem. Thanks @n1md7