# How do I store data from form and display it on a new page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a form with 2 input fields. When you press submit it should take you to a new page and display the input data.

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Film survey</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="./Success.html">
      <h1>Movie survey</h1>
      <p>Thank you for participating in the film festival!</p>
      <p>Please fill out this short survey so we can record your feedback</p>

      <div>
        <label for="film">What film did you watch?</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="film" name="film" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="rating"
          >How would you rate the film? (1 - very bad, 5 - very good)
        </label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="rating" name="rating" required />
      <div><button class="submit">Submit</button></div>
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my js code

```
const formEl = document.querySelector("#form");

formEl.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {

  event.preventDefault();


  const formData = new FormData(formEl);


  fetch("https://reqres.in/api/form", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      film: formData.get("film"),
      rating: formData.get("rating"),
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {

      window.location.href = "./Success.html";
    })
    .catch((error) => {

      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

I have a second html page called Success.html which I want to display tha data given in the form. I need to make a mock API so I tried using reqres.

This is my Success.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Success</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Thank you for your feedback!</h1>
    <p>You watched: <span id="film"></span></p>
    <p>You rated it: <span id="rating"></span></p>
    <script>
  
      const formData = JSON.parse(request.body);

      const filmEl = document.querySelector("#film");
      const ratingEl = document.querySelector("#rating");

      filmEl.textContent = formData.film;
      ratingEl.textContent = formData.rating;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I thought this would work but I get this error after pressing submit:

`` Success.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined
at Success.html:16:35

Answer (score 1):

The line  `const formData = JSON.parse(request.body);` in your `success.html` is trying to reference a variable named `request`, which isn't defined in the scope of the `<script>` tag that it's contained in - that's why you're getting  the `ReferenceError: request is not defined` error.

[This other Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765694/9090160) seems similar to yours - I have linked you to an answer that I think would be helpful. In short, you could pull the values you care about out of your `response`, then pass them via query parameters to be displayed in your `success.html`.

Along those same lines, it might make sense for your mock API to respond with a 302 status code and location header including film and rating query parameters that points to your success page.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass along data between web pages in several ways, using JSON data `{ foo: 'bar' }` as an example:

**1. Use URL parameter:**

- Stringify and URL encode your JSON response (full or needed data only), and pass along via a URL parameter
- Example: `'data=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))`, resulting in `data=%7B%20foo%3A%20'bar'%20%7D`
- Keep in mind that there is a limit to URL length, varying from 2k to 64k depending on browser

**2. Use browser local storage:**

- The quota is browser specific, in range of 5-10MB, e.g. much larger than URL length
- To set in the form page: `localStorage.setItem('myFormData', JSON.stringify(data));`
- To read in success page: `let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myFormData');` (you likely want to add some error handling)

**3. Temporarily POST data**

- You post the JSON data back to the server to `/success`
- Your success page is delivered dynamically via a server side script that receives the data via a POST, and regurgitates it as JSON or in any other preferred format
- Extra work, so not recommended

Having listed that, why not show the content in the form page itself? You can easily update the DOM using native JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: I can't display it on the form page because it is a task I received. It is demanded that the form redirects to a success page that lists the answers that were given.