# Passing a PyScript variable from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables, pyscript

I am trying to use a variable which I created using PyScript on one page in another page. [This post initially seems to propose a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page), but when importing the variables, it turns out that they have been stored using (what I assume to be) their `__repr__()` function. That is obviously problematic for, among others, Pandas objects.

Page 1:

```
<py-script>
    # Code that generates these objects is omitted

    js.localStorage.setItem("dtypes", dtypes)
    js.localStorage.setItem("df", df)
    js.localStorage.setItem("target", target)
</py-script>
```

Page 2:

```
<py-script>
    import js

    dtypes = js.localStorage.getItem("dtypes")
    df = js.localStorage.getItem("df")
    target = js.localStorage.getItem("target")

    js.console.log(dtypes) # Returns the stored dictionary as a string
</py-script>
```

Is there a way to retain these variables as Python objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I misunderstood what `setItem()` and `getItem()` do. From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem), it follows that `value` must be a string (and otherwise will apparently be converted to a string representation).

Thus, my solution for storing Pandas DataFrames or Series is as follows, using [`to_csv` without specifying the `path_or_buf` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#:%7E:text=If%20None%2C%20the%20result%20is%20returned%20as%20a%20string.):

Page 1:

```
js.sessionStorage.setItem("df", df.to_csv())
```

Page 2:

```
df = js.sessionStorage.getItem("df")
df = io.StringIO(df)
df = pd.read_csv(df)
```